# Remove welcome video on dotnetnuke new install

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have just installed DNN and the website loads successfully. It allows me to login with the host user but a second or 2 later it overlays a "Welcome to Evoq" youtube video which I can't close. I have to close it in order to get to the admin screens to apply my customisation. There is no close option and no scroll bar

I have installed DNN9 on Windows 10, SQLServer Azure db, IIS 10

Note that I am new to DNN and this is my first install. Any guidance will be most appreciated

Comment: I would start over again and specifically start with DNN 9.08.01. There are some good videos out there on installing DNN and watching one or two might reveal the detail or step you need to get things working. Its usually pretty easy and just works. If you are just installing a local copy to play with, I highly recommend you give nvQuickSite v2.x a try.

Comment: And did you mean SQL Server Azure or SQL Server Express? I assumed you meant Express.

Comment: Thank you for the advice Jeremy. I have done the reinstall with an earlier version as suggested and everything is now working as expected!

Comment: I moved my comment to an answer, if you come back again, maybe give me Answer credit? TIA

Answer (score 0):

I would start over again and specifically start with DNN 9.08.01. There are some good videos out there on installing DNN and watching one or two might reveal the detail or step you need to get things working. Its usually pretty easy and just works. If you are just installing a local copy to play with, I highly recommend you give nvQuickSite v2.x a try.